# What is file descriptor of a network socket? and how to get it?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, file-descriptor

I was wondering what is a file descriptor of the network socket and how to get it? I believe it is a number?

Comment: You already have it. You don't have anything else. The result of socket() is it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed a number and you get it by issuing the [`socket(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/socket) system call. It is stored in the process's `task_struct` and you need it to send or receive data.

More exactly, the kernel uses the file descriptor to locate `File Objects` stored in the `files_struct` struct inside the `task_struct`. It behaves like a bitmap where the number of the file descriptor represents the position the `File Object` occupies inside that structure.

Answer (score 2):

What is 'the' network socket? If it's a socket you created, it will be the return value from socket() or accept(). If you're writing a daemon, the socket will be determined by whatever did the accept() on your behalf -- for example, /etc/xinetd will set it to 0, 1, and 2.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that accept() will return another file descriptor.